# Windows Server 2012 r2 show all control panel items

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

How to make Windows Server 2012 R2 to show "All Control Panel Items" by default, when Control Panel is opened?

Comment: The answer is the same for both client and server Windows systems, and it's purely a user interface issue; it has nothing to do with system administration, so it's off topic here. Let's move this to SuperUser.

Comment: Sorry for posting to the wrong place, I agree that question should be moved to SuperUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default shortcut on the Start screen will always open the Control Panel using the category view, regardless of any settings you might use; but if you open the Control Panel using the desktop icon, or by using the actual "Control Panel" icon in the full Start menu (accessible using the down arrow on the Start screen, or by typing "control panel" on the same Start screen to search for it), the view settings will stick.

So, you need to open the Control Panel using the desktop icon or the Start menu icon (but ***NOT*** the pinned icon on the Start screen), and select the view you prefer; the next time, if you open the Control Panel in the same way, it will use the same settings.

You can also remove the default Control Panel icon from the Start screen, scroll down to (or search for) the "real" Control Panel icon in the Start menu and pin ***that*** to the Start screen; this will let you easily open the Control Panel, but in a way which will save your view settings.

And no, I don't know the reason for this crazyness; it looks like the default Control Panel icon on the Start screen is somewhat different from the Control Panel icon on the desktop or on the Start menu. Why... only Microsoft knows.

See [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/windows-8-control-panel-view-by-settings-will-not/8b623dce-5b3c-4924-a5c1-787d5c83d8bd?auth=1) for a discussion.

Comment: Thank you, the reason why "All Control Panel Items" was not saved as a default view - I always used address bar for navigating to All Control Panel Items, after using `View by:` control state was saved.